# C# ASP.Net Processing Issue - Reading Table While Deleting Rows

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, locking

Simply, I have an application that has one page that deletes and then re-adds/refreshes the records into a table every 30 seconds.  I have another page that runs every 45 seconds that reads the table data and builds a chart.

The problem is, in the read/view page, every once in a while I get a 0 value (from a max count) and the chart shows nothing.  I have a feeling that this is happening because the read is being done at the exact same time the delete page has deleted all the records in the table but has not yet refreshed/re-added them.

Is there a way in my application I can hold off on the read when the table is being refreshed?

Best Regards,
Andy

- C#
- ASP.Net 4.5
- SQL Server 2012

My code below is run in an ASP.Net 4.5 built Windows service.  It deletes all records in the ActualPlot table and then refreshes/adds new records from a text file every 30 seconds.  I basically need to block (lock?) any user from reading the ActualPlot table while the records are being deleted and refreshed.  Can you PLEASE help me change my code to do this?

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Open the SAP text files, clear the data in the tables and repopulate the new SAP data into the tables.

        var cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TaktBoardsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
        SqlConnection conndetail = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
        SqlConnection connEdit = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
        SqlCommand cmdGetProductFile = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader reader;
        string sql;

        // Delete all the records from the ActualPlot and the ActualPlotPreload tables.  We are going to repopulate them with the data from the text file.

        sql = "DELETE FROM ActualPlotPreload";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Delete Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            Library.WriteErrorLog(msg);

        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }


        sql = "DELETE FROM ActualPlot";
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
        {
            string msg = "Delete Error:";
            msg += ex.Message;
            Library.WriteErrorLog(msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        // Read the SAP text file and load the data into the ActualPlotPreload table

        sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [BoardName], [ProductFile], [ProductFileIdent] FROM [TaktBoards].[dbo].[TaktBoard] ";
        sql = sql + "JOIN [TaktBoards].[dbo].[Product] ON [Product].[ProductID] = [TaktBoard].[ProductID]";

        cmdGetProductFile.CommandText = sql;
        cmdGetProductFile.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdGetProductFile.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();
        reader = cmdGetProductFile.ExecuteReader();

        string DBProductFile = "";
        string DBTischID = "";
        string filepath = "";

        string[] cellvalues;

        DateTime dt, DateCheckNotMidnightShift;
        DateTime ldSAPFileLastMod = DateTime.Now;
        string MyDateString;
        int FileRecordCount = 1;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            DBProductFile = (string)reader["ProductFile"];
            DBTischID = (string)reader["ProductFileIdent"];

            filepath = "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\WebApps\\TaktBoard\\FilesFromSAP\\" + DBProductFile;
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(filepath); // Open file
            ldSAPFileLastMod = fileInfo.LastWriteTime; // Get last time modified

            try
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);

                FileRecordCount = 1;

                // Populate the AcutalPlotPreload table from with the dates from the SAP text file.

                sql = "INSERT into ActualPlotPreload (ActualDate, TischID) values (@ActualDate, @TischID)";
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    cellvalues = sr.ReadLine().Split(';');

                    if (FileRecordCount > 1 & cellvalues[7] != "")
                    {
                        MyDateString = cellvalues[7];
                        DateTime ldDateCheck = DateTime.ParseExact(MyDateString, "M/dd/yyyy", null);

                        DateTime dateNow = DateTime.Now;
                        string lsDateString = dateNow.Month + "/" + dateNow.Day.ToString("d2") + "/" + dateNow.Year;

                        DateTime ldCurrentDate = DateTime.ParseExact(lsDateString, "M/dd/yyyy", null);
                        string lsTischID = cellvalues[119];

                        if (ldDateCheck == ldCurrentDate)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                conndetail.Open();
                                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conndetail);
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActualDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TischID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                                cmd.Parameters["@TischID"].Value = cellvalues[119];

                                MyDateString = cellvalues[7] + " " + cellvalues[55];
                                dt = DateTime.ParseExact(MyDateString, "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss", null);

                                cmd.Parameters["@ActualDate"].Value = dt;

                                // Ignore any midnight shift (12am to 3/4am) units built.

                                DateCheckNotMidnightShift = DateTime.ParseExact(cellvalues[7] + " 6:00:00", "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss", null);
                                if (dt >= DateCheckNotMidnightShift)
                                {
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                }

                            }
                            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
                            {
                                string msg = "Insert Error:";
                                msg += ex.Message;
                                Library.WriteErrorLog(msg);
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                conndetail.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    FileRecordCount++;

                }
                sr.Close();

            }


            catch
            { }


            finally
            { }



        }

        conn.Close();


        // Get the unique TischID's and ActualDate from the ActualPlotPreload table.  Then loop through each one, adding the ActualUnits
        // AcutalDate and TischID to the ActualPlot table.  For each unique TischID we make sure that we reset the liTargetUnits to 1 and 
        // count up as we insert.

        SqlCommand cmdGetTischID = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader readerTischID;
        int liTargetUnits = 0;
        string sqlInsert = "INSERT into ActualPlot (ActualUnits, ActualDate, TischID) values (@ActualUnits, @ActualDate, @TischID)";

        sql = "SELECT DISTINCT [ActualDate], [TischID] FROM [TaktBoards].[dbo].[ActualPlotPreload] ORDER BY [TischID], [ActualDate] ASC ";

        cmdGetTischID.CommandText = sql;
        cmdGetTischID.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdGetTischID.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();
        readerTischID = cmdGetTischID.ExecuteReader();

        DBTischID = "";
        DateTime DBActualDate;
        string DBTischIDInitial = "";

        while (readerTischID.Read())
        {
            DBTischID = (string)readerTischID["TischID"];
            DBActualDate = (DateTime)readerTischID["ActualDate"];

            if (DBTischIDInitial != DBTischID)
            {
                liTargetUnits = 1;
                DBTischIDInitial = DBTischID;
            }
            else
            {
                liTargetUnits++;
            }


            try
            {
                conndetail.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, conndetail);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActualUnits", SqlDbType.Real);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ActualDate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TischID", SqlDbType.VarChar);

                cmd.Parameters["@TischID"].Value = DBTischID;
                cmd.Parameters["@ActualDate"].Value = DBActualDate;
                cmd.Parameters["@ActualUnits"].Value = liTargetUnits;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            }
            catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
            {
                string msg = "Insert Error:";
                msg += ex.Message;
                Library.WriteErrorLog(msg);
            }
            finally
            {
                conndetail.Close();
            }
        }

        conn.Close();

        Library.WriteErrorLog("SAP text file data has been imported.");
    }
```

Comment: Could you add your SQL queries? Chances are, with a bit of transaction management and locking hints we can get this working in a way that doesn't cause your SELECT to return 0 rows.

Comment: Cory could you give me a hand with this, I've added my code.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If the data is being re-added right back after the delete (basically you know what to re-add before emptying the table), you could have both operation within the same SQL transaction, so that the data will be available to the other page only when it has been re-added.

I mean something like that :

```
public bool DeleteAndAddData(string connString)
    {
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
        {
            OleDbTransaction tran = null;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                tran = conn.BeginTransaction();
                OleDbCommand deleteComm = new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM Table", conn);
                deleteComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                OleDbCommand reAddComm = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Table VALUES(1, 'blabla', 'etc.'", conn);
                reAddComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

                tran.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tran.Rollback();
                return false;
            }

        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your queries don't take too long to execute, you can start the two with a difference of 7.5 seconds, as there is a collision at every 90 seconds when the read/write finishes 3 cycles, and read/view finishes 2 cycles.

That being said, it's not a fool-proof solution, just a trick based on assumptions, in case you wan't to be completely sure that read/view never happens when read/write cycle is happening, try considering having a Read Lock. I would recommend reading [Understanding how SQL Server executes a query](http://rusanu.com/2013/08/01/understanding-how-sql-server-executes-a-query/) and [Locking in the Database Engine](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190615(v=sql.105).aspx)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a couple of things:

1. Make sure your `DELETE` + `INSERT` operation is occurring within a single transaction:

   ```
   BEGIN TRAN
       DELETE FROM ...
       INSERT INTO ...
   COMMIT
   ```
2. If this isn't a busy table, try locking hints your `SELECT` statement. For example:

   ```
   SELECT ...
   FROM Table
   WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
   ```

   In the case where the update transactions starts while your `SELECT` statement is running, this will cause that transaction to wait until the `SELECT` is finished. Unfortunately it will block other `SELECT` statements too, but you don't risk reading dirty data.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to figure this out but I changed my code so the program was not deleting all the rows in the ActualPlot table but checking to see if the row was there and if not adding the new row from the text file.